# PayPal SDK for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, paypal

I'm creating an app and I need in app payments (not GooglePay or ApplePay)
There lots of in app payments plugins! but they are all not supported in my country...
I searched for more than 3 days and found 0 plugins that support my country.
My last resort is PayPal but from my searches there is no plugin for flutter or any tutorial on youtube.
I really really need this to work, I don't care if it is PayPal or any other in app payment method, just so it can work in my country.
Can someone help me?

P.S.:
I'm from Israel

Answer (score 3):

Edit: There is a new Native Checkout SDK for Android and iOS: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/

---

Old answer:

If you need a native SDK, you can use PayPal's Braintree Mobile SDK to accept payments to any normal PayPal business account.

In addition to that SDK running in your app, you will also need a webservice/server to run the server-side portion of this integration.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/

Comment: Is this the easiest way to get the "Pay with PayPal" in Flutter/Dart?

Comment: It is the way that uses a native SDK.  The *easiest* way is with a link of the form:

https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=My%20easy%20PayPal%20button&amount=10%2e99&currency_code=USD&business=myemail@somewhere.com

Comment: Braintree is not supported in Israel, will it affect the process? and is there a full guide on how to do what you described on video? I have a hrad time just doing what I read from the page.. they assume a lot of stuff and things like that

Comment: Braintree Direct (the fully payment gateway) is not supported in Israel.  PayPal payments via the Braintree Mobile SDK are supported, following the linked guide on developer.paypal.com

Comment: Is there any video showing how to do it? I found nothing.

Comment: Video? No. Sample code, maybe. This plugin seems to have an option for standalone PayPal (no dropin UI, which you do not want): https://github.com/DeligenceTechnologies/Braintree-Payment-Gateway-for-Flutter -- however, it probably authenticates with gateway credentials, and you will be using a braintree access token from developer.paypal.com .  So, you will need to modify the sample code to use a different credential type, at least on the server end

Comment: @PrestonPHX could you explain how to use this link "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=1XA23050E0755520C&useraction=commit&mfid=1614294631387_befb12173decf" in my project?

Comment: That's a link of a checkout in progress, so there's no way or reason to use it directly. Use one of the normal integration methods for whatever your environment is.